# How to use button that is in an xib in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using a segmetn controller and I put a view and created two xib, as the segment index changes I change the xib, however I would like to disable the segment click and make the change through a button that I insert in each xib, but not I can not make this change, nor the print I put inside the button is working. Does anyone know how I can solve it?

I'll post the code too.

here is the code for the segment controller.

```
import UIKit

class SegmentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Segment: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    var view1 : UIView!
    var view2 : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1 = primeiraViewController().view
        view2 = segundaViewController().view
        containerView.addSubview(view1)
        containerView.addSubview(view2)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func testes(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch Segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            containerView.addSubview(view1)
            break
        case 1:
            containerView.bringSubview(toFront: view2)
            break

        default:
            break
        }

    }

}
```

here is the xib code

```
import UIKit

class primeiraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func teste(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print("afjkakfasfa")

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: because you keep the _view_ part only and implicitly chuck the _controller_ part away.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand very well, how could I do this?

Comment: that is the part when you keep the _view_ only and chuck the _controller_ away: `view1 = primeiraViewController().view`, so... you need to do something like that instead: `viewController1 = primeiraViewController()`, as part of the fire you'll also need a `var viewController1 : UIViewController!` in your class and obviously later it should look like this: `containerView.addSubview(viewController1.view)`... it is messed up a bit but that is the brief idea and such little changes could help you to keep the _controller_ alive as well in this little project.